# Preceding row without impact of WHERE clause

Tags: sql, presto

I need to get a preceding row even if doesn't match conditions in WHERE.
Here is my data:

[image]

I need to get the request_id of the row preceding the row with flag=true
In example above it would be the one at 2022-09-10 07:02:04 (please disregard the hilghlight, I didn't notice there is earlier one)

I can use LAG:

```
SELECT LAG(request_id, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY time) 
FROM table
WHERE flag=true
```

But flag=true conditon will apply to LAG function too.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE as (
SELECT time
     ,CASE WHEN flag=true THEN LAG(request_id, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY time)  END as prev_request_id
FROM table
)

select time,  prev_request_id
from CTE
  WHERE prev_request_id is not null
```

Figured I can do it with CASE but not sure if it is efficient way doing it. The flag is quite rare and I think it would be good to filter out requests that don't have it

Comment: As long as you get your results, that's step one.  I don't think I ever understand the ask very well.  :)   I was thinking you need the session id regardless and then any subsequent session id's that are marked true.  Either way glad you got your answer!